# Is there an email notification for crash reports in App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Wondering if it is possible to get an email notification each time my app crashes on some ios device out there?

I know there is a similar question from 8 years ago about iTunes Connect.
Wishing there is now an option, with the time that has passed and now that it's App Store?!?

Comment: I’m not sure this is something that makes sense for Apple to offer. I’d have to imagine there are quite a big portion of developers in the program for which this feature would effectively nuke their mail servers. Can’t you just pull the crash logs from the iTunes Connect portal periodically?

Comment: Well, whoever doesn't want the notifications should always be able to turn them off... and I'm not talking about the crash logs, but rather just to be aware when there is a sudden rise in crashes.

Comment: This is precisely what a tool like [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics) is for. We have it set up to post crash notifications in a Slack channel, and it can be configured for other kinds of notification.